# Is it possible to upload a folder and its files to sharepoint in a single click

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Am really new to sharepoint and i need to upload a site in sharepoint.The site contents(html,image files) are in my local system.When i try to upload in sharepoint i was not able to upload the entire folder in one click.Instead one by one only i can able to create.Initially i need to create all the folders manually and then was uploading the file one by one **Using the add ew document and Add new folder button**.

I tried even automating by c#, but there using

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect
```

only one file was created at a time.

Is it possible to create entire folder in share point in a single click or can it be achieved through any API.Or i should only loop through folders and create files ony by one.

> Am using sharepoint client dll

Answer (score 2):

One option at you hand using OOTB is to use "Open with Explorer". You will find this option under the Library ribbon tab.

[image]

This will open your Library in Windows Explorer and you can them simply copy-paste your entire folder over here and it will get uploaded over to SharePoint Library. Note that, this option only works with Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Also you could use SharePoint Designer, it has Drag and Drop support for folders as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Drag and drop option` or you can `open document library with explorer view` and copy your folder there.

For more information refer [This link](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/11/29/how-to-upload-multiple-documents-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: I was using sharepoint 2010

Comment: The same options are available in SP 2010. Here is a link for SP 2010: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2010/05/sharepoint-2010-windows-explorer-view.html

Answer (score 0):

If you already have working C# code that uploads a file, can you add a loop around it to add all the files?

Something like

foreach (string path in Directory.GetFiles(sourcedir))
{
}